# Angr with 'No bytes in memory for block starting at'

Tags: angr

I am playing with the project here: https://github.com/foreverbell/angr-rust-example

After running `make solve`, I cannot get the desired output.

I added `print(sm.errored)` to the end of the script and get

```
...
65 <SimulationManager with 1 active> 1
66 <SimulationManager with all stashes empty (1 errored)> 0
[<State errored with "No bytes in memory for block starting at 0x23930.">]
```

I played around with several other examples and the same problem `'No bytes in memory for block starting at'` occured.

I changed `full_init_state` to `entry_state` in the code, and the code works somewhat normally (I am able to get the output).

This is the full code I am using:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import angr
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == "main":
  p = angr.Project("build/main")
elif sys.argv[1] == "bench":
  p = angr.Project("build/bench")

state = p.factory.entry_state()
state.options.add(angr.options.BYPASS_UNSUPPORTED_SYSCALL)

sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(state)
sm.use_technique(angr.exploration_techniques.dfs.DFS())

dep = 0
while len(sm.active) > 0:
  dep += 1
  sm.step()
  print(dep, sm, len(sm.deadended + sm.active))
  for s in sm.deadended + sm.active:
    stdin = s.posix.dumps(0)
    stdout = s.posix.dumps(1)
    if stdin and (b"yes" in stdout):
      print(stdin)
      exit()

print(sm.errored)
```

I do not know if it is a problem with my installation of angr or if something changed that breaks `full_init_state`, but I found that I frequently encounter 'No bytes in memory for block starting at' on other large binaries even with `entry_state`. So I want to know if I am doing something wrong with my installation or workflow here.

For the record, I am using `angr_dev` for installation of angr.